# ControllerAs not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am trying to follow best practise and switch to ControllerAs.  In this case I am attaching the controller using ui-router. I have a SPA with two views and one works fine, but the other does not.

In my HTML I refer to main.resto.* elements, but also have a `{{main.test}}`.  None show.

Weirdly, I can get the elements to show if:

- I remove the `$watch` functions (not all show below for brevity); or
- I use an ng-controller attribute on the parent div in the view's template (see below).

Weirdly, the last 3 assignments are leading to correct behaviour in the Controllers that also use this data. And when I follow progress through dev tools, everything seems to execute.  (If I add a `$scope.$apply()` at the end it complains a digest is already underway.)

Can anyone see something wrong, and explain why it is so inconsistent?

```
.controller 'RestoCtrl', ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Restos, Dictionary) ->

    main = this
    $scope.data = Restos.data
    main.test = "hello World"
    main.data = Restos.data
    main.areas = Dictionary.areas

    # Wait for ajax loaded data
    $scope.$watch 'data.restos', () ->
        if Restos.data.restos.length
            if $stateParams.qname
                return setResto $stateParams.qname if Restos.data.restos.length

    setResto = (qname) ->
        tmp = Restos.data.restos.filter (r) ->
            return r.qname == qname
        main.resto = tmp[0]

        main.data.pageTitle = "Review: " + main.resto.rname
        main.data.headTitle       = main.resto.rname + ": " + main.cuisine + " restaurant review by Amsterdam Foodie"
        main.data.metaDescription = main.resto.rname+": "   + main.resto.comment
```

Note that if I add the Controller on a div in the view (as below), then it does work (but then I can't update data used by the navbar).

```
<div ng-include="'components/navbar/navbar.html'"></div>

<div class="container" itemscope itemtype='http://schema.org/Restaurant' ng-controller="RestoCtrl as main">
```

Comment: Someone just added a comment suggesting to `return main` at end of controller.  That WORKED! But I do not understand why that was not necessary on my other view, and also not necessary when I added the `ng-controller` statement in this view. That is weirdly inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was the one who added that comment.

Basically you need to `return main` as the last line of the controller.
Really sorry, but I do not know the reason for that.